# Код на puppeteer не выполняет свою функцию?

Tags: javascript, парсер, google-chrome, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=1&structure=ETF&dividend_frequency=Monthly');

    const rows = document.querySelector('div#mobile_table_pills table')
        .querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

    for (const row of rows) {
        const lastCellText = row.querySelector('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').innerText;
        if (lastCellText === 'A+' || lastCellText === 'B+') {
            console.log(row.querySelector('[data-th="Symbol"]').innerText);
        }
    }

    await page.screenshot({path: 'etfdb.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

выдает ошибку

Comment: `ReferenceError: document is not defined` - откуда тут возьмётся `document`?

Comment: посмотри как тут обрабатывается контент страницы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1188487/2659

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1193976/176064 Не нужно создавать копии одного и того же вопроса. Вопрос можно редактировать, каждое редактирование вопроса подымает вопрос в ленте.